# How to update this in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to update one value in Firestore. I have checked a few pages can't find simple solution. I would prefer to avoid using FirebaseUser.uid.

This is how collection is added:

```
Map<String, String> userDataMap = {
              "userName": usernameEditingController.text,
              "userEmail": emailEditingController.text,
              "account": userType,
              "deleted": "false",
            };
databaseMethods.addUserInfo(userDataMap);

Firestore.instance.collection("users").add(userData).catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
    });
```

**I want to find user with his email and I stack with this:**

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you will have only 1 single user with a particular `email`. So, you can use the first document as the data:

```
final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
    .get();

if (querySnapshot.docs != null && querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  final doc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(doc.id)
      .set(userDataMap);
}
```

But this is not a good approach as we are doing a lot of computation both at Firebase & at our app as well. This is the reason, we should set some sort of `id` in the document for easier access or update operations.

If you were using `user.uid` as the document id, the whole process would become so easy as shown below:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(userDataMap);
```

We don't have to fetch a list of `DocumentSnapshot` & iterate over it & the update based on that document's `id`.

Comment: How can I save data in a document named with user.uid? And how can I get this id later?

Comment: Or please, just explain to me how with doc named with user id (second option) change only one value - "deleted" from "false" to "true"

Comment: You will have to create a `Map<String, dynamic>` & change its value. For example, lets say you have a field `deleted` then, to update its value, you can call the method:
`await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).update({'deleted': true});`